# What is more secure? VNC or Citrix or HTTPS

Tags: security, https, vnc, citrix

What is more secure? VNC or Citrix or HTTPS

So they all have the same amount of security.

Don't they use the same encryption algorithms in they end?

Comment: VNC sucks and is slow. Try NX -- http://freenx.berlios.de/ or http://www.nomachine.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which is safer, a chainsaw or a motorcycle? The answer is, it depends on how you use them.

VNC doesn't provide security by itself, but is generally used with an encryption wrapper such as VPN, SSH, stunnel, etc. Citrix might support SSL directly, which I guess makes it more secure as-is, though the way VNC is typically used is just as secure.

I don't know what HTTPS is doing in that list. It's like comparing a chainsaw and a motorcycle.

Comment: A chainsaw and a motorcycle are both dangerous to use!

Answer (score 2):

Neither VNC nor HTTP are secure. VNC can be tunneled over SSH to be secure. HTTP can be tunneled over SSL/TLS to be secure (https).